# Strange Y-Axis on Flot Js

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm using Flot Js to generate this graph:
[image]

My problem is on Y-Axis, it starts at 23:00:00 and ends in 23:00:00 too. My goal is Y-Axis start at 00:00:00 and ends at 23:59:59.

My js code is:

```
$(function() {
    var data1 = [
    ["Pedro",gt(2015,05,13,20,01,00)],["João",gt(2015,05,13,07,09,00)],["José",gt(2015,05,13,00,00,00)],["Gustavo",gt(2015,05,13,13,00,00)],["Tenico Hotel",gt(2015,05,13,01,00,00)],["Gualter",gt(2015,05,13,23,25,00)],["Joao",gt(2015,05,13,02,30,00)],["José",gt(2015,05,13,00,00,00)],["Maria",gt(2015,05,13,00,00,00)],["Avatar",gt(2015,05,13,00,00,00)]     ];

    function gt(year, month, day,hours,min,secs){
        return new Date(year, month-1, day,hours,min, secs).getTime();
    }

    var chart = $("#chart");

    $.plot(chart, [data1],{
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.3,
                align: "center"
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            tickLength: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%H:%M:%S",
            min: (new Date("2015/05/13 00:00:00")).getTime(),
            max: (new Date("2015/05/13 23:59:59")).getTime(),
            tickSize: [1,"hour"]
        }
    });
    chart.resize();
});
```

Already had searched and don't find any clue why this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into timezone issues.

If you add 'UTC' to your min and max date strings, your y-axis goes from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

I've created a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkawarcx/) to demonstrate. You'll have to work with the dates in your data array to get them into UTC as well.

[Flot's API.md](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) elaborates on how it handles dates:

> Default behavior is that Flot always displays timestamps according to
>   UTC. The reason being that the core Javascript Date object does not
>   support other fixed time zones. Often your data is at another time
>   zone, so it may take a little bit of tweaking to work around this
>   limitation.

You could also [set the timezone](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) of your axis by specifying (from the Flot API.md):

```
yaxis: {
    mode: "time"
    timezone: null, "browser" or timezone (only makes sense for mode: "time")
}
```